# Best way to fire up an event once even if the parent rebuilds the child?

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

Say you have a stateful widget (name it `ÌnterstitialAd`) which implements a Google AdMob interstitial ad; you placed it in the parent splash screen in the hope it shows the ad up.

Unfortunately, the splash makes some `setState()` hence triggering the rebuild many times.

As a consequence, `ÌnterstitialAd` triggers many interstitial ad.

What would be the best approach to prevent this issue?

Comment: The best way is, to use a state manager like bloc,getX, etc in your project, and exit your widget from `stateful` to `stateless`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to trigger the function in `initState()` with a delay.

Like with `Future.delayed()`. This will ensure the method is called only once.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    getRoutes();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      //Trigger some method here, it will execute only once
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

If you need to call the method from inside of build method try as below:

```
    bool isTriggered = false;
    
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        if(!isTriggered){
              //Trigger some method here
            isTriggered = true;
        }
        return Scaffold(
            body: Column(
                children: [
                 
                ],
           ),
        );
    }
```